# Getting Postgres to allow outside connections

Tags: postgresql

I have a new Oryx Pro from System76 running Pop! OS 22.04.  I have installed and configured Postgres, which runs fine locally.  However, I cannot get it to accept outside connections.

In `postgresql.conf`, I have changed:

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

to:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In `pg_hba.conf`, I changed:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

to:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0              scram-sha-256    

# IPv6 local connections:
host     all             all             ::0/0                  scram-sha-256
```

I made sure to shutdown PostgreSQL after any edits, and then restart it.

Here's the output from starting (after changes):

```
waiting for server to start....
2023-03-19 19:35:35.759 CDT [26902] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, 64-bit  
2023-03-19 19:35:35.759 CDT [26902] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-03-19 19:35:35.759 CDT [26902] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-03-19 19:35:35.760 CDT [26902] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-03-19 19:35:35.765 CDT [26905] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-03-19 19:35:25 CDT
2023-03-19 19:35:35.770 CDT [26902] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
done
server started
```

And here's `netstat -na|grep 5432`:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     666762   /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

It's as though Postgres is not seeing either `postgresql.conf` or `pg_hba.conf`, but from making other changes, I'm pretty sure it is seeing them.

And here's `sudo ufw status`:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

And here's the output from an attempted remote connect with `psql -h 192.168.50.136 -U postgres`:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "192.168.50.136", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: Connectio locally and run `SHOW hba_file;` and `TABLE pg_hba_file_rules;` and see if the output is as you expect.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I've been (stupidly) working on files in /etc/postgres/... rather than /var/lib/postgres/... (why are there two sets of these files???).  I'm embarrassed to say how long I've spent trying to figure this out (so I won't).  Again, thank you!

Comment: To be clear, Laurenz Albe pointed me directly to the solution to my problem.

Comment: For PostgreSQL installed via apt on Ubuntu, /etc/postgresql is the correct location for those files, and those config files don't exist at all in /var/lib/postgresql/.  It seems like you, or maybe Pop!, has done something quite weird in setting up your system.